# Ignite Memory Consumption vs Redis

Tags: ignite

I am new to Ignite, comparing Ignite with Redis to identify an in-memory data store for my use case. 
I have the following Ignite Setup - Apache.Ignite 2.5 for C#.Net, 3 nodes, partitioned data, off-heap memory, and using Data Streamer to write data into cache store.

I have loaded the same data into Redis and Ignite. Redis' memory usage is 11gb, whereas in Ignite with 3 nodes, the memory usage in all nodes add up to 69gb. Based upon the description here: https://apacheignite.readme.io/docs/capacity-planning, considering the Indexes and nodes, I expected the memory usage in Ignite to be upto 2x of that in Redis.

Is this expected? Are there any memory recommendations/configuration for .Net version that could help reduce the memory consumption?

Comment: Do you have backups configured with Apache Ignite?

Comment: No, backups are not configured.

Comment: Can you share your config and data model?

Comment: How did you measure the occupied space? Did you look at the memory, or disk?

Comment: Looked at the memory. Persistence is not enabled.

Comment: We will need more details about your use case.